Возможно ли на C# сделать осознанный генерирующий текст похожий на GPT с помощью ML .NET
Пытаюсь разобраться как можно сделать что-то похожее ( хотя-бы что-то игрушечно в пет-проекте ), чтобы модель могла генерировать условные цитаты, условно осмысленные предложения, которые мы как люди прочитав это поймём, что он имел ввиду. Если есть у кого-то идеи куда копать, пожалуйста расскажите об этом

Ну наверное можно. Нужно смотреть, какая нужна для этого конфигурация нейросети и сделать такую же на ML.NET.

Скажу честно, такое невозможно. Точней не так... Вы не сделаете на текущий момент адекватное решение. Почему? 1. Данные. Для того, чтобы ваша модель выдавала что-то более менее адекватное, имела "сознание" как у GPT, она должна иметь много, очень много качественных, разнообразных данных, вы сможете собрать датасет из, ну скажем, нескольких миллионов условных "цитат"? Ой сомневаюсь.. 2. Чем больше данных, тем больше требуется времени и ресурсов для создания самой модели и для ее содержания на сервере, а это именно серверное решение....

@EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ваш комментарий, я понимаю, что это серверное решение, возможно я понимаю что потребуется очень много данных, чтобы обучить модель, просто суть вопроса даже не в том, чтобы собрать эти данные и натренировать модель, а в том, чтобы имея текущий ML .NET Построить модель, которая сможет хотябы тренироваться на чём-то менее глобальном
И мне стало интересно, есть ли такая возможность, построить эту модель в рамках .NET

Нету. Даже предложенная выше Phi - это очень кастрированная и ограниченная модель, которая вряд-ли удовлетворит ваши потребности и которая даже не знает адекватно русский. Так что, если хотите подобное, то лучше смотрите в сторону платных сервисов с API доступом, увы, нынче только так. Вон к примеру Coze, весьма интересный сервис, который позволяет даже свои документы загружать, на основе которых модель будет давать ответы.

@EvgeniyZ Благодарю, вы меня не впервый раз выручаете своим ответом :)

Генерировать модели ИИ (AI) на C# можно с помощью ONNX Runtime.
Ссылки:
https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/genai
https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-genai
Пример:
Phi-3-mini in 30 lines of C# with ONNX Runtime GenAI
https://nietras.com/2024/04/28/phi-3-mini-csharp-ortgenai
